# Any passbook design tool for designer

Tags: objective-c, json, ios6, passbook

I would like to know if there are any tool to design a layout of passbook.

I didn't find any in xcode. Experienced designer can read and write a simple json but it is much better if there are any tool help to speed up this design process.

Answer (score 8):

The Pass Designer is available at http://create.passkit.com

You can use it for free to easily design and create Passes that appear in the web interface exactly as they appear in Passbook.

And with a Developer Account you can quickly build your own income stream! Details to be announced soon.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand the **Passbook** app, as you are limited to what you can change from Apple.

There is a Session Video called

> [Session 301 - Introducing Passbook, Part 1](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16352034415)

you can see it in a [web browser](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=301) as well.

This will explain you the model and what can you change as types, colors, texts.

If you're only trying to find a PhotoShop file to "play around", give [Takahashi Alex](http://dribbble.com/takahashi_alex) it's own [Passbook GUI PSD](http://dribbble.com/shots/677761-Passbook-GUI-PSD) a go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the creator of [Passdock](https://api.passdock.com), that is exactly what you are looking for. It's a web design tool that let you create a Pass without knowing anything of the JSON structure. It's free and you can also use it to delivery the passes to the devices.

I'll be happy to help you if you have any question.

Comment: Please could you post an example in objective-c to create a pass using Passdock ?

Thanks

Dario

Answer (score 0):

You can make passbook file via http://passsource.com .

In this site, you can test customization of passbook.